# Binary random array with a specific proportion of ones?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

What is the efficient(probably vectorized with Matlab terminology) way to generate random number of zeros and ones with a specific proportion? Specially with Numpy?

As my case is special for `1/3`, my code is:

```
import numpy as np 
a=np.mod(np.multiply(np.random.randomintegers(0,2,size)),3)
```

But is there any built-in function that could handle this more effeciently at least for the situation of `K/N` where K and N are natural numbers?

Comment: Do you need the proportion to be *exactly* the given value, or is that just the expected proportion of the sample?

Comment: Also, what should happen for the 1/3 case when `size` is not divisible by 3? Exception? Round/floor/trunc? Weighted random round (so 10 has a 2/3 chance of 3 and a 1/3 chance of 4)?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, its the expected proportion in my case. I wished you didn't deleter your answer so I would have accepted it.

Comment: @abarnert, that was the expected case!

Comment: @Naji: I restored my answer.  If you had needed the exact proportion, that method wouldn't work.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, and I accepted it! Well even my method was not exact as I make a random sequence first!

Comment: @Naji: A binomial or other random distribution functon won't give you a 2/3 chance of 3 and a 1/3 chance of 4; it'll give you a high chance of 3, a lower chance of 4, an even lower chance of 2, an even lower chance of 5, etc. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @abarnert, a binomial sample with N=2 and p=ration will generate whatever I want I believe!

Comment: @Naji: Thanks, but I think I like @Jaime's answer more than mine.  It seems even more explicit.  For an arbitrary proportion `frac`, just use `p=[1-frac, frac]`.

Comment: @Naji: Whatever you want? I wanted it to generate a trillion dollars, and all it gave me was an array. I suppose I'm not believing hard enough. ;)

Comment: @abarnert, ha ha ha! good one! well you know what I mean :)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, then the Oscar goes to Jaime! :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you might get some help with [numpy.random.shuffle](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html)

```
>>> def rand_bin_array(K, N):
    arr = np.zeros(N)
    arr[:K]  = 1
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr

>>> rand_bin_array(5,15)
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.])
```

Answer (score 131):

Yet another approach, using [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
>>> np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(10,), p=[1./3, 2./3])
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: note that this approach will *not* give you the exact proportion of zeros and ones you request . . . the answer by @mdml below will.

Comment: true, and since it is accepted, I think Cupitor might have added a bug to his program

Comment: @JFFIGK, dbliss: this was discussed in the comments to the question.  Those comments are still there, so take a look.

Comment: Since the mentioned link is broken, see: [numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

Answer (score 51):

A simple way to do this would be to first generate an `ndarray` with the proportion of zeros and ones you want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 100
>>> K = 30 # K zeros, N-K ones
>>> arr = np.array([0] * K + [1] * (N-K))
>>> arr
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Then you can just `shuffle` the array, making the distribution random:

```
>>> np.random.shuffle(arr)
>>> arr
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Note that this approach will give you the *exact proportion* of zeros/ones you request, unlike say the binomial approach. If you don't need the exact proportion, then the binomial approach will work just fine.

Comment: How stupid of me! Right I forgot about binary distribution. Actually somebody posted binary right before you but he deleted his answer(dont know why!!)

Comment: This is quite clever

Answer (score 22):

You can use `numpy.random.binomial`. E.g. suppose `frac` is the proportion of ones:

```
In [50]: frac = 0.15

In [51]: sample = np.random.binomial(1, frac, size=10000)

In [52]: sample.sum()
Out[52]: 1567
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the correct proportion of ones like mdml's answer does.

Comment: @John, this was discussed in the  comments to the question.  Take a look.

Comment: I see now! Of course the question needs editing then as it asks for specific proportion.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner: you can avoid using lists of integers and probability distributions, which are unintuitive and overkill for this problem in my opinion, by simply working with `bool`s first and then casting to `int` if necessary (though leaving it as a `bool` array should work in most cases).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.random(9) < 1/3.
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False])   
>>> (np.random.random(9) < 1/3.).astype(int)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the correct proportion of ones like mdml's answer does.

Comment: The OP said they wanted 1/3 to be the expected proportion of 1s, not the exact proportion.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting the exact number of ones and zeroes is to sample indices without replacement using `np.random.choice`:

```
arr_len = 30
num_ones = 8

arr = np.zeros(arr_len, dtype=int)
idx = np.random.choice(range(arr_len), num_ones, replace=False)
arr[idx] = 1
```

Out:

```
arr

array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a `nd-array` with random binary members (0 and 1) directly in one line through the following method. You can also use `np.random.random()` instead of `np.random.uniform()`.

```
>>import numpy as np
>>np.array([[round(np.random.uniform()) for i in range(3)] for j in  range(3)])
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
>>
```