# Creating an Array with an equal number of 0 and 1 in a random order?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, random, shuffle

Before I explain, here is my code for reference:

```
import numpy as np 

arrayteam = [[3,3,3,3,3,3],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
#nteams = 3
#nsubteam = 2

#newnums = np.zeros((len(arrayteam),len(arrayteam[0])))

subteam = [] 
for i in range(len(arrayteam)):
    subteam.append(np.random.choice([0,1],size=len(arrayteam[i]),p=[0.5,0.5]))

print (subteam)
```

Here is the output:

```
[array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]), array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])]
```

As you can see, it randomly chooses 0s and 1s which is what I want, however the number of 0s and 1s is unequal in each array, obviously because I have it as p=0.5, so there's a 50% chance it will choose 0 or 1. I want to have it so that there are 3 zeros and 3 ones in each array, but they occur in a random order. How can I do this?

Also, how can I end up changing exactly where I want the zeros and ones to occur? For example, what if I want the first 3 numbers in the array to be 0s, and the second 3 to be ones? Or what if I want them to alternate?

Comment: I'd populate with half zeros and half ones, then shuffle.

Comment: I'm confused, why not just `arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]) ; np.random.shuffle(arr)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary random array with a specific proportion of ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597473/binary-random-array-with-a-specific-proportion-of-ones)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+random+binary+array+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @DeepSpace the reason I had it that way is for another code because I am technically assigning the numbers in the array to be "team 0" and "team 1"

Answer (score 3):

Use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle). Note that it shuffles in-place, and returns `None`:

```
import random
length = 3
subteam = [0] * length + [1] * length
random.shuffle(subteam)
print(subteam)
```