# Create a 3D tensor of zeros with exactly one '1' randomly placed on every slice in numpy/jax

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, jax

I need to create a 3D tensor like this (5,3,2) for example

```
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 0]]])
```

There should be exactly one 'one' placed randomly in every slice (if you consider the tensor to be a loaf of bread). This could be done using loops, but I want to vectorize this part.

Comment: `t.sum(axis=(1,2)) == 1`?

Comment: well yes. but i want to randomly generate t. @QuangHoang

Comment: See some of the techniques discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597473/binary-random-array-with-a-specific-proportion-of-ones

Comment: @blorgon I went through those. none can satisfy the one per slice condition

Comment: You could certainly apply the techniques in that post, but @QuangHoang 's answer is quite clever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try generate a random array, then find the `max`:

```
a = np.random.rand(5,3,2)
out = (a == a.max(axis=(1,2))[:,None,None]).astype(int)
```

Comment: This is not a great approach, because there is a small but nonzero chance that the maximum will appear more than once, leading to multiple 1s in a slice.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to do this is probably to create an array of zeros, and set a random index to 1. In NumPy, it might look like this:

```python
import numpy as np

K, M, N = 5, 3, 2
i = np.random.randint(0, M, K)
j = np.random.randint(0, N, K)
x = np.zeros((K, M, N))
x[np.arange(K), i, j] = 1
```

In JAX, it might look something like this:

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random

K, M, N = 5, 3, 2
key1, key2 = random.split(random.PRNGKey(0))
i = random.randint(key1, (K,), 0, M)
j = random.randint(key2, (K,), 0, N)
x = jnp.zeros((K, M, N)).at[jnp.arange(K), i, j].set(1)
```

A more concise option that also guarantees a single `1` per slice would be to use broadcasted equality of a random integer with an appropriately constructed range:

```python
r = random.randint(random.PRNGKey(0), (K, 1, 1), 0, M * N)
x = (r == jnp.arange(M * N).reshape(M, N)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a zero array where the first element of each sub-array is 1, and then `permute` it across the final two axes:

```py
x = np.zeros((5,3,2)); x[:,0,0] = 1

rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.permuted(rng.permuted(x, axis=-1), axis=-2)
```