# random number with specific condition in python

Tags: numpy, random

I'd like to generate an int random number between 0 and 1 n number of times. I know the code to generate this:

`num_samp = np.random.randint(0, 2, size= 20)`

However, I need to specify a condition that say 1 can only appear a number times and the rest should be zeros. For instance if I want 1 to appear only 5 times from the above code, then I would have something like this [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Can someone help with the code to generate something like this? Thanks

Comment: Hardly random.  I'd loop over each value in the array and code in your requirement for max occurrences.

Comment: After reading answers, I realize that we all replied differently, and it is hard to know who is right. Do you want exactly 5 '1'? Or at most 5? Do you want them to be distributed with 50/50% chance, until there are 5 of them, or to be distributed equally?

Comment: My answer, for example, gives exactly 5 '1', all places with an equal chance to be 1. So, even the first number do not have a 50/50 chance to be '1' (only 25% chance with N=20,k=5). Scott's answer gives at most 5 '1' (some indices could be equals. As shown in their example, with only 4 '1'), and with a probability of having k '1' quite complicated (not really complicated to compute, but unlikely to be the one you wanted). Your question seems to imply that you want first a 50/50 chance, then a 0% chance to be '1' (like drawing a coin at first, until 5 '1' are drawn, then fill with 0)

Comment: So, not easy to know for sure what is an acceptable answer for you. Plus, there might be a XY problem here. What is it you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary random array with a specific proportion of ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597473/binary-random-array-with-a-specific-proportion-of-ones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then it looks more like shuffling an array with 0 and 1.

```py
N,k=20,5 # Total number of wanted numbers, and of 1
arr=np.zeros((N,), dtype=int)
arr[:k]=1
np.random.shuffle(arr)
# arr now contains random 0 and 1, with only 5 1. Like this one:
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `numpy.random.choice()`
It picks a random number from a range  and can accept a probability distribution.